# Deployment of a MERN-Stack on AWS and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mern, react-fullstack

i am learning the MERN-Stack since 2000 hours and want to deploy a website (and later an app with react-native) on AWS for production.

I am new to the deployment-stuff and i am not sure how to exactly use what services. Because i want to create a real business, the structure should be at least a bit safe(so that no one with a bit knowledge can hack it real easy, but its also dont need to be so safe, that not even the NSA could hack it). Also it should have no real performance issues for at least 20.000 daily users (i know it will be very hard to get to this point, but i want to plan for the future). The website should be basically a plattform where everyone can upload texts and other people can search for texts and read it (so that you can estimate the performance-capacity).

Here is my plan:

A. Deploy the React-Frontend on S3 and put Cloudfront in front of it (already done).

B. Use a EC2-server with NGINX to run the backend with node and express.

C. Connect the EC2-server to mongodb via connection string. So the database will not hosted in my AWS-Account or on the EC2-server.

D. Then let the front-end send it requests to my EC2-server (checked it with a test-ec2-server and postman, and it worked).

So my questions:

1. Is this configuration okay? Even for production? Or it is only for development and there a other best practices? I am a bit uncertain if am doing here a really big "noob" mistake and running the site will cost me a few hundreds dollars a month or go down, if the traffic will go up a bit. Or i will get easily hacked by some random script from the internet.
2. It is a problem to let database host on mongo (i would buy the mongoDB Atlas serverless) or should i move it directly to my AWS-Account (like RDS or DynamoDB) or on my EC2-Server, because of security or performance reasons? I would prefer to stay in mongo, because i dont want to learn another database :D
3. I know there is also the possibilty to use AWS EB but for some reason i would prefer EC2. Will it handle the traffic or there are some extreme security issues to host the backend by myself on EC2?
4. It is a problem that theoretically everyone could make requests to my backend without my frontend (i have a express-rate-limiter as middleware and some other basic security packages)? Theoretically there should be no problem, but i am a bit afraid, that i am forgetting a big problem. It feels "strange" that everyone could use it (at least the public routes, that need no account on my website and in my database).
5. It is a problem when my backend has only a random number as IP and no real domain name? I would say no, but again uncertain.

Sorry for the questions, that could maybe sound stupid. Also maybe i am to overconfident and i should learn more of the basics of deployment, than i am also sorry to bother you.

Comment: so sad not anyone commented here yet. i think it would be very helpful if someone explain it.